# unpolite or impolite

Tags: adjectives

can one say "unpolite"? As in the following sentence: "it's hard for me to be unpolite." I was in class today and my teacher asked me to give him an example of an infinite sentence and that came out of my mouth just because, but my teacher corrected me. And told me to say "impolite" instead, but I found acouple of threads on the internet with opposed ideas. So please help me with this one.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions should demonstrate some research effort, for example, by quoting dictionary definitions— the ODO definition for *[unpolite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unpolite)* says *impolite is now more usual in this sense*, and there is no entry at all in most learners' dictionaries. This suggests that *unpolite* is, at least, very rare. If you believe the other "threads on the Internet" are reliable, you should include them as well. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

In modern English, the correct term is "impolite".

However, Google Ngrams shows that two hundred years ago, [it was more common to say "unpolite"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unpolite%2Cimpolite&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunpolite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpolite%3B%2Cc0).

Both in- (im-) and un- are used for different adjectives, I don't think there is a rule for which one to choose. Sometimes it changes even for adjectives and nouns that have the same root, for instance: *unstable* but *instability*.